# How to filter nested serializers in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a viewset like this:

```py
class PizzaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PizzaCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaCategorySerializer
    model = PizzaCategory
```

My serializers are:

```py
class PizzaCategorySerializer(CustomModelSerializer):
    pizzas = PizzaSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PizzaCategory
        fields = "__all__"
        
class PizzaSerializer(CustomModelSerializer):
    images = PizzaImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
    model = Pizza
    fields = "__all__"
```

My endpoint shows something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "pizzas": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "images": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/305ced93-8f6.jpg",
            "title": "pizza.jpg",
          }
        ],
        "price": "10.00",
        "name": "my pizza example",
        "category": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "big cheese",
  },
  ...
```

My problem: I need to filter my result by price (example, price equal to 5).

In my mind, something like this should work:

```py
 pizzas = PizzaSerializer(Pizzas.objects.filter(price=5), many=True)
```

But no, nothing change. Can I how to filter correctly this?

Answer (score 0):

class PizzaCategorySerializer(CustomModelSerializer):
pizzas = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
class Meta:
    model = PizzaCategory
    fields = "__all__"
def get_pizzas(self, obj):
    try:
        queryset = Pizzas.objects.filter(price=5)
        serializer = PizzaSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return serializer.data
    except:
        return None
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but does not work. My endpoint not show filtered results.